# Bitcoin core savemempool

Tags: bitcoin-core

Bitcoin JSON RPC has `savemempool` command for saving mempool data to the disk. However, it seems like saved file is binary. How can I read this file in human readable format?

https://developer.bitcoin.org/reference/rpc/savemempool.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DumpMempool() and LoadMempool() in src/validation.cpp](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/99602/dumpmempool-and-loadmempool-in-src-validation-cpp)

Comment: You can also check how this is implemented in  https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/kernel/mempool_persist.cpp written in C++, where DumpMempool() function is responsible for dumping the contents of a transaction mempool to a file and LoadMempool() function is responsible for loading the contents of the mempool from a specified file on disk. To read the transactions, you would need to create a similar LoadMempool function in your chosen programming language and parse the structured objects: uint64_t version ... up to unbroadcast_txids.

Comment: Is there any Python code that can read mempool.data file?